# Display Image from mysql database to fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am new to fpdf. i can fetch required data from database and generate the pdf. but i would like to fetch the images from database and display that in the generated pdf. i have stored my images into a image folder. and the image name is stored in the db. please give me a tutorial with example. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

The Html2Pdf is a nice library to generate your pdf files.

http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Answer (score 0):

For more detail --
go on below link http://www.fpdf.org/

and then click on mannual there is lot of options there.

take a look at below example taken from same place --

$pdf->Image('path toimage with image name logo.png',10,10,-300);

// Insert a dynamic image from a URL
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');